# Initializing a textbox value in with Option Strict On

Tags: vb.net

I tried to initialize a textbox value by using the `.Text` property

```
Textbox.Text = 0
```

But Im getting the error `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'String'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these will work:

```
TextBox1.Text = 0.ToString()
TextBox1.Text = CType(0, String)
TextBox1.Text = CStr(0)
TextBox1.Text = "0"
```

With option strict on you cannot be ambiguous about your conversions. You need to explicitly state what you are setting values to.

It thinks that TextBox1.Text is a string data type, and that 0 is an integer data type, therefore throwing the error. Convert the 0 to a string before setting them equal.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly whats wrong.
Use `Textbox.Text = "0"` or don't use `Option Strict`.